# Include All day events in CAML query for a date

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I'm querying SharePoint for calendar events given a date.  This works for events other than **all day events**.  Event dates in SharePoint are stored as UTC except for all day events which are stored as the local site timezone.  How would I include all day events in the `CAML` query?  This is my CAML query which works for events for a date.  It checks for `EventDate` and `EndDate` for a date and for events that have started but haven't ended.

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Or>
        <And>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value StorageTZ='FALSE' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2018-07-03T00:00:00-0700</Value>
          </Geq>
          <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
            <Value StorageTZ='FALSE' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2018-07-03T23:59:59-0700</Value>
          </Leq>
        </And>
        <And>
          <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value StorageTZ='FALSE' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2018-07-03T00:00:00-0700</Value>
          </Leq>
          <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
            <Value StorageTZ='FALSE' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2018-07-03T00:00:00-0700</Value>
          </Geq>
        </And>
      </Or>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

I've looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520651/sharepoint-all-day-events-behave-differently-in-caml-query) but couldn't get the `DateRangesOverlap` in this `CAML` to work.

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />
                    <Value Type='AllDayEvent'>1</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Geq>
                    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime'>
                        <Today />
                    </Value>
                </Geq>
            </And>
            <DateRangesOverlap>
              <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
              <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
              <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
              <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>
                  <Today />
              </Value>
            </DateRangesOverlap>
        </Or>
       <Geq>
          <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
          <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>
             <Today />
          </Value>
       </Geq>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

I want to add this to my `CAML` so the query includes **all day events** but I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example that will request any Sharepoint Calendar event ( doesnt matter if it is an "all day event" or not:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
  <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="False" Type="DateTime">
          <Today />
        </Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="fAllDayEvent" />
        <Value Type="Text">False</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="False" Type="DateTime">
            <Today OffsetDays='-1' />
        </Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />
        <Value Type="Text">True</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Take into account that **"all day Event" Events** are considered by Sharepoint as if they were starting **the previous day**.

**EXAMPLE:**

- Some event is created for the 2nd of July, and saved as an "all day
  event".
- We add a new (calculated) column to our SP Calendary library, "Real
  Start Date" => =DAY([Start Time])
- Calculated date column will tell 1st of July, instead of 2nd.

If you modify your filtering so it contains dates that start with **(targetDate -1) and** "**allDayEvent**" to **true**, you will **reach the expected results** ;)

On the other hand, depeding on which time zone is defined for your site, you may need to change the  value.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520651/sharepoint-all-day-events-behave-differently-in-caml-query)

Comment: Remember that not all time zones are UTC -hrs. Some are UTC+ so if the local time zone is e.g. Australia then this won't work. Also for times that = UTC (Like the UK in winter)

Comment: Yes thats true. However, what I mean with the answer is that the "all day" events are interpreted in a funny way. I had also issues retrieveing the event in certain period of time ( including the "all day" event ones ), and I have to do multiple filters and play with the  "IncludeTimeValue=Yes/No" value